# windows 10 на Dell с ssd 256 с установленной ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu

Как установить windows 10 на Dell с ssd 256 с предустановленной ubuntu 16.04 lts не повредив ubuntu ?    Можете пошагово, для простого пользователя?...       А так, чтобы одновременно работали обе OS ?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что оффтопик.

Comment: @Suvitruf, вряд ли. У нас уже есть куча вопросов, связанных с установкой различных ОС.

Comment: @Arhad но это не значит, что это норма же =/ Я не имею ничего против вопросов по администрированию и т.п, но, блин, вопрос по установке OS - это как-то уж слишком оффтопик.

Comment: Жаль, что и здесь не нашёл компетентного ответа.  Видимо придётся сносить ubuntu.